# Filter rows in data.frame based on the length of values in all groups

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have a data.frame like this:

```
df<-data.frame( Id = paste0("g",1:6),
a= c(6:11),
b = c(10:13,NA,NA),
c = c(7:10,NA,10),
d = c(NA,7:9,NA,13),
e= c(NA,6:10),
f= c(NA,NA,NA,4:5,NA))
colnames(df)=c("ID",rep("normal",3),rep("patient",3))

> df
  ID normal normal normal patient patient patient
1 g1      6     10      7      NA      NA      NA
2 g2      7     11      8       7       6      NA
3 g3      8     12      9       8       7      NA
4 g4      9     13     10       9       8       4
5 g5     10     NA     NA      NA       9       5
6 g6     11     NA     10      13      10      NA
```

this df contains data for two groups (normal and patient).I am going to perform some analysis for all rows, therefore all groups in each rows must have at least two values.I used the following codes to filter the rows that all groups have not at least two values.

```
    fx=function(x){length(x[!is.na(x)])>=2}
    f1=apply(df[,2:4], 1,fx)#filter based on group normal
    f2=apply(df[,5:7], 1,fx)#filter based on group patient
    df=subset(df,f1&f2)
> df
  ID normal normal.1 normal.2 patient patient.1 patient.2
2 g2      7       11        8       7         6        NA
3 g3      8       12        9       8         7        NA
4 g4      9       13       10       9         8         4
6 g6     11       NA       10      13        10        NA
```

but these codes are useful for a data with limited groups. my main data have 100 groups(and all groups have 3 replicates),`colnames(df)=paste0("grp",sort(rep(1:100,3)))`
 therefore I need some simple codes to filter the rows in a data.frame with 100 groups.

**my goal: delete the rows that have not at least two values in each groups.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could differentiate `"normal"` and `"patient"` columns and select the rows using `rowSums`

```
normal_cols <- grep("normal", names(df))
patient_cols <- grep("patient", names(df))
df[rowSums(!is.na(df[normal_cols])) >= 2 & rowSums(!is.na(df[patient_cols])) >= 2,]

#  ID normal normal normal patient patient patient
#2 g2      7     11      8       7       6      NA
#3 g3      8     12      9       8       7      NA
#4 g4      9     13     10       9       8       4
#6 g6     11     NA     10      13      10      NA
```

---

Or using the `fx` function you have defined we can use `apply` twice on both set of columns and select the rows using `subset`.

```
fx = function(x) {length(x[!is.na(x)])>=2}
subset(df, apply(df[normal_cols], 1,fx) & apply(df[patient_cols], 1,fx))
```

Answer (score 3):

Could do:

```
library(dplyr)

names(df) <- paste0(names(df), 1:ncol(df))

df %>%
  filter(
    rowSums(!is.na(select(., contains("normal")))) >= 2 &
      rowSums(!is.na(select(., contains("patient")))) >= 2
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use `reshape` to get a long format and look at the `colSums`.

First rule in such matters are app**R**opriate column names, i.e. `<chr_prefix>.<num_suffix>`.

```
names(df) <- c("ID", paste(rep(c("normal", "patient"), each=3), 1:3, sep="."))
```

Now we `reshape` into long format and split `by` `"ID"`. We only want those IDs where `all` `colSums` are `> 2`, we store this in a vector `s` with which we may subset the data frame `df`.

```
r <- reshape(df, idvar="ID", direction="long", varying=list(2:4, 5:7), times=1:3)
s <- by(r[-1], r$ID, function(i) all(colSums(i, na.rm=TRUE) > 2))
df[s, ]
#   ID normal normal normal patient patient patient
# 2 g2      7     11      8       7       6      NA
# 3 g3      8     12      9       8       7      NA
# 4 g4      9     13     10       9       8       4
# 6 g6     11     NA     10      13      10      NA
```

#### Data

```
df <- structure(list(Id = structure(1:6, .Label = c("g1", "g2", "g3", 
"g4", "g5", "g6"), class = "factor"), a = 6:11, b = c(10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, NA, NA), c = c(7, 8, 9, 10, NA, 10), d = c(NA, 7, 8, 
9, NA, 13), e = c(NA, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), f = c(NA, NA, NA, 
4L, 5L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```